# Zsh: Expanding hashed directory names in prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

I am experimenting with moving from bash to zsh, and in particular with the hash function; so that

```
hash -d Do=~/Downloads
```

means I can enter `cd Do` to move immediately to that directory.  Nice.  But in the prompt, the directory is given as `~Do` instead of `~/Downloads` which is what I'd prefer to see.  Is there any way of using directory hash values so that the prompt expands to the full directory name (with an initial `~` if in the user directory)?

Answer (score 2):

The [prompt escape](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state) `%~` abbreviates the current directory using hashed directories whenever possible. To stop using directory abbreviations, you can use `%/` instead, but that doesn't abbreviate the home directory either.

To abbreviate the home directory only, set the [`prompt_subst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) option (this may require adding additional backslashes in places in your prompt). Instead of `%~` or `%/`, use a manual expansion from `$PWD`.

```
setopt prompt_subst
PS1='%B${${PWD/#%$HOME%/\~\/}/#$HOME/\~}\$%b '
```

If you want to perform more complex substitutions, you can set a variable in the [`chpwd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd) hook and use it in your prompt. Even for the simple case shown above, this approach is more verbose but arguably more readable.

```
setopt prompt_subst
chpwd () {
  case $PWD in
    $HOME/*) prompt_PWD=\~/${PWD#$HOME};;
    $HOME) prompt_PWD=\~;;
    *) prompt_PWD=$PWD;;
  esac
}
PS1='%B$prompt_PWD\$%b '
```

You may prefer a hybrid approach that expands only certain hashed directories. This is easy to plug into the `chpwd` approach (or even into the direct approach, but it's less readable). For example, the following `chpwd` command abbreviates only directories that start with `/home` (presumably other users' home directories) and that aren't under your home directory.

```
chpwd () {
  case $PWD in
    $HOME/*) prompt_PWD=\~/${PWD#$HOME};;
    $HOME) prompt_PWD=\~;;
    /home/*) prompt_PWD=${(%)${:-%~}};;
    *) prompt_PWD=$PWD;;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a trailing `/` to the directory name would achieve the desired effect.